# how to enable the scroll bar in the text area when using pointer-events: none

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, scss-mixins

scrollbar is disabled when I used the `pointer-events: none` css in the text area.

I want the scroll bar to be enalbed to scroll and view whole content but the textarea shouldn't be editable.
I want to fix this issue only in the css.

I tried many solution but nothing helped me

here i've kept my code in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a9vxurqo/

kindly help me in this

I tired this solution but didn't helped me https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollarea-wider-forked-sz9qnf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please include your code in your question. You can do this with the `<>` icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in HTML by adding [the readonly attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly) to the textarea, like this:

```html
<textarea rows="4" class="input" readonly>
content
content
content
content
content
content
content
content
content
content
content
content
content
content
content
</textarea>
```

I don't see a way to do this with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why don't you use `readonly` attribute to a `<textarea>` element as this attribute alone effectively create the expected situation (non-editable textarea but users can scroll through the contents).

However, since you specifically asked for workaround using CSS only, both `resize: none;` and `pointer-events: none;` together prevent editing and resizing while enabling scrolling.

The following worked for me:

```
.input {
  resize: none;
  pointer-events: none; 
}
```

Comment: it didn't work Can you apply this CSS to this https://jsfiddle.net/a9vxurqo/